# How do I select files in a folder based on part of filename and zip them in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, zip

I'm fairly new to Powershell(using Powershell 2.0 btw) and am trying to make a script that does several things(this is my 3rd script or so). I have most things in place but the last thing remaining is to group files of different types (xml, tfw and tif) in a folder, based on the first part of the filename(first three characters) and then zip these files into several zip-files with name like the first 3 characters, either in the same location or in a new one.

Sample of folder content:

```
001.tif
001.tfw
001.metadata.xml
002.tif
002.tfw
002.metadata.xml
003.tif
003.tfw
003.metadata.xml
003_svel.tif
003_svel.tfw
003_svel.metadata.xml
```

Wanted result:

```
001.zip containing 001.tif, 001.tfw, 001.metadata.xml
002.zip containing 002.tif, 002.tfw, 002.metadata.xml
003.zip containing 003.tif, 003.tfw, 003.metadata.xml, 003_svel.tif,
003_svel.tfw and 003_svel.metadata.xml
```

I have installed 7-zip to do the zipping and am using the commandline version. I've used 7-zip local on some testfiles and got it to work, but then it was only tif-files. I have a source folder where I search for the latest created folder and then process the files in it.
This is what I have so far(Powershell 2.0):

```
$dir_source = "c:\Test"
$new_folder = Get-ChildItem $dir_source -Recurse |
Where { $_.PSIsContainer} | 
Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty    Fullname <-First 1
Get-ChildItem $new_folder -recurse -Exclude metafile.xml | 
Group-Object {$_.Name.Substring(0,3)}
```

This gives me a list of grouped files in the lates created folder based on the first 3 characters in the filename. It also show what files are in each group. 
Like below:

***Count Name                      Group

----- ----                      -----

    3 003                       {C:\Test\20150708 063255_B\003.metafile.xml, C:\Test\20150708 063255_B\003.tfw, C:\Test\20150708 063255_B\003.tif}

    6 004                       {C:\Test\20150708 063255_B\004.metafile.xml, C:\Test\20150708 063255_B\004.tfw, C:\Test\20150708 063255_B\004.tif,C:\Test...
    6 009                       {C:\Test\20150708 063255_B\009.metafile.xml, C:\Test\20150708 063255_B\009.tfw, C:\Test\20150708 063255_B\009.tif,C:\Test...***

Now my next step ist to take these groups and zip them. Ideally create these zip-files in a different destination directory (I believe I can change this when setting the $directory- variable in the script below.)

```
foreach ($group in $dataset) { 
                $name = $file.name 
                $directory = $file.DirectoryName
                $zipFile = $file.Name + ".zip" 
                sz a -t7z "$directory\$zipfile" "$directory\$name"
```

This last code is causing some trouble. I either get the message:

> 7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18 Error:
>   c:\Test\Dest_test460.zip is not supported archive System error:
>   Incorrect function.

,or

> WARNING: Cannot find 1 file 7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010
>   Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18 Scanning \460:  WARNING: The system cannot
>   find the file specified.

,or it starts zipping all files on my userprofile into a zip-file. Depending on changes I do to the $group-value. I believe there are one ore more basic errors in my script causing this, and this is where I'm asking for some help. It may be that I am approaching this the wrong way by first grouping the files I want and then try to zip them?

Anyone that can see my error or give me some hint to what I have to do?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not get the suggested solution to work, had problems configuring ICSharpCode. I also wanted to use 7zip, since it is still under some updating regime.

Ended up copying my files to temp folders based on the filenames and then zip each folder. After that delete the tempfolders with files. Ugly code, but it does the job.

```
# Create folder based on filename and copy files into respective folder
Get-ChildItem $new_folder -Filter *.* | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer} | Foreach-Object{

$dest = Join-Path $_.DirectoryName $_.Name.SubString(0,3)

if(!(Test-Path -Path $dest -PathType Container))
{
    $null = md $dest
}

$_ | Copy-Item -Destination $dest -Force

}

# Create zip-file of each folder
dir $new_folder | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | ForEach-Object { sz a -t7z -mx9 "$dir_dest\$_.zip" $_.FullName }
# Delete temp-folders
dir $new_folder | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | Remove-Item -Recurse
```

Answer (score 0):

Lee Holmes New-ZipFile do the job, he has two versions one of them using the ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll to compress, and the other not require it, i wrapped the 2nd one into a function:

```
Function New-ZipFile {

param(
## The name of the zip archive to create
$Path = $(throw "Specify a zip file name"),
## Switch to delete the zip archive if it already exists.
[Switch] $Force
)
Set-StrictMode -Version 3
## Create the Zip File
$zipName = $executionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath($Path)
## Check if the file exists already. If it does, check
## for -Force - generate an error if not specified.
if(Test-Path $zipName)
{
if($Force)
{
Remove-Item $zipName -Force
}
else
{
throw "Item with specified name $zipName already exists."
}
}
## Add the DLL that helps with file compression
Add-Type -Assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
try
{
## Open the Zip archive
$archive = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open($zipName, "Create")
## Go through each file in the input, adding it to the Zip file
## specified
foreach($file in $input)
{
## Skip the current file if it is the zip file itself
if($file.FullName -eq $zipName)
{
continue
}
## Skip directories
if($file.PSIsContainer)
{
continue
}
$item = $file | Get-Item
$null = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::CreateEntryFromFile(
$archive, $item.FullName, $item.Name)
}
}
finally
{
## Close the file
$archive.Dispose()
$archive = $null
}

}
```

To use it for example:

```
dir c:\folder -Recurse | New-ZipFile -Path c:\temp\folder.zip
```

The Source file(for the one that use the ICSharpCode): http://poshcode.org/2202

Comment: Hi. This should also work but where does this take into consideration the first 3 letters of the filenames? (I've updated my question with sample.)

Answer (score 0):

Use my Previous Answer Function New-ZipFile and use with this one:

```
$FolderName = "C:\temp" 
$Files = dir $FolderName 
$prfx = @()
foreach ($file in $files)
{
$prfx += $file.Name.Substring(0,3)
}

$prfx = $prfx | Group

foreach ($Prf in $prfx)
{
$prf = $prf.name.ToString()
dir $Files | ? {$_.Name -match "^$prf"} | New-ZipFile -Path "$foldername\$prf.zip"
}
```

According to your example It will output 3 zip files like you want,
it will always use the first 3 letters of the file, you can the change this in this line `$prfx += $file.Name.Substring(0,3)` and set it different if needed.

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks, but so far I'm not able to get this to work, and I feel your suggested zip-code is a lot more complicated that using 7zip. Isnt your suggestion on grouping is basically the same as my solution? -- Get-ChildItem $new_folder -Recurse -Exclude metafile.xml | Group-Object {$_.Name.Substring(0,3)} --